# Change the Currency Symbol thoroughout the Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, currency, cultureinfo

I derive the controllers from a base class:

```
namespace merawi.Controllers
{
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public CultureInfo trTR = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");

        public BaseController()
        {
            trTR.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "TL";
        }
    }
}
```

and use this statement to format the currencies:

```
ViewBag.SellingPrice = sp.ToString("C", trTR);
```

However, in the views which has viewmodels like

```
@model List<merawi.Models.DocumentWorkStep>
```

I need a way to format the currencies as desired.

`SellingPrice` is a decimal field in the `DocumentWorkStep` class:

```
public Nullable<decimal> SellingPrice { get; set; }
```

and using this

```
<td>@string.Format("{0:C}", res.SellingPrice)</td>
```

outputs ₺, I need "TL"

I need a way to access the trTR object from the view files...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your web.config file, assuming that you want the same culture to be used in your entire application:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization uiCulture="tr-TR" culture="tr-TR" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I add the globalization tag in the web.config file, also, since we need to customize the culture format(such as using `"."` instead of `","` as decimal in `FR-CA`), I add a customization in Global.asax.vb, which can set the globalization globally.

Web.config:

```
<globalization culture="fr-CA" uiCulture="fr-CA"/>
```

Global.asax.vb:

```
Private Sub MvcApplication_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.BeginRequest
    StartSession()
    Dim  info as new Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString())
    info.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = "."
    info.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."
    info.NumberFormat.PercentDecimalSeparator = "."
    info.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ","
    info.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ","
    info.NumberFormat.PercentGroupSeparator = ","
    info.NumberFormat.
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info
End Sub
```

That's my case. Hopefully it helps. Thank you.

Comment: what is that StartSession()? Is that something related to your code?